# Converting T-SQL to LINQ with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to convert my T-SQL to LINQ. It's giving me a real headache. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
T-SQL
select 
  h.DateStamp
, h.Machine
, h.SalesInvoice 
, h.Status
, sum(i.Quantity)                                           totalquantity
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='SALES', i.Quantity, 0))               as SalesQty
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='RETURNS', i.Quantity, 0))             as ReturnQty
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='SALES',   i.Quantity*i.Soldsrp , 0))  as SalesGross
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='RETURNS', i.Quantity*i.Soldsrp, 0))   as ReturnGross
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='SALES',   i.DiscountAmount , 0))      as SalesDiscount
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='RETURNS', i.DiscountAmount, 0))       as ReturnDiscount
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='SALES',   i.TotalAmount , 0))         as SalesACD
, sum(IIF(h.[Status]='RETURNS', i.TotalAmount , 0))         as ReturnACD

from CSHR_SalesItems i
left join CSHR_SalesHeader h on h.SalesOrderNum = i.SalesOrderNum
where H.DateStamp between '2015-08-20 00:00:00.000' and '2015-08-27 23:59:00.000' 

group by h.DateStamp, h.Machine, h.SalesInvoice, h.[Status]
```

Here is my attempt to turn it into LINQ with entity framework. GroundCommander is the entity

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())
{
    foreach (var item in GC.CSHR_SalesItems)
    {
         var Summary =
             from i in GC.CSHR_SalesItems
             join h in GC.CSHR_SalesHeader on item.SalesOrderNum equals h.SalesOrderNum into IH
             from h in IH
             where (h.DateStamp >= dateTimePickerStart.Value && h.DateStamp <= dateTimePickerLast.Value)                 
             select new { 
                h.DateStamp,
                h.Machine,
                h.SalesInvoice,
                h.Status,
                i.Quantity //need to get the sum
             };
    }
```

Comment: You need `from h in IH.DefaultIfEmpty()` to make it a left join.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Though I don't think you need a left join at all as the where will be false when the left side is null.

Comment: Also did EF create a navagation property in `CSHR_SalesItems` that give you a list of values in `CSHR_SalesHeader`?  It will be easier to use that then doing the join in the first place.

Comment: No it did not create a nav poperty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
var Summary =
    from i in GC.CSHR_SalesItems
    join h in GC.CSHR_SalesHeader on item.SalesOrderNum equals h.SalesOrderNum 
    where (h.DateStamp >= dateTimePickerStart.Value 
           && h.DateStamp <= dateTimePickerLast.Value)      
    group new { item = i, header = h} 
       by new {h.DateStamp, h.Machine, h.SalesInvoice, h.Status} into grp
    select new { 
        grp.Key.DateStamp,
        grp.Key.Machine,
        grp.Key.SalesInvoice,
        grp.Key.Status,
        TotalQuanity = grp.Sum(x => x.item.Quantity),
        SalesQty = grp.Where(x => x.header.Status == "SALES").Sum(x => x.item.Quantity),
        ...
    };
```

First I've got rid of the left join because any time the right side is `null` that where would be false anyway.  Second I added the group by which will create the appropriate grouping.  Then in the select you can do you're sum for the total and I've given you an example of how to filter based on the status for your other totals.

Comment: I'm curious what SQL would be generated for this, and if it would be as efficient as hand-coding it.

Comment: You can use SQL Server Profiler to see what is created.  Usually EF SQL is a lot harder to read.  You can run both in SSMS to see if the execution plans differ any.

Comment: I'm trying it out now. Reading the code so far looks right. Thanks so far